# tengo una cuestion que solucionar para un bucle en el cual recorro varias listas dentro de un diccionario(python)

Tags: python

Tengo q escribir un programa que te ayude a llevar un registro de tus gastos. El programa te hará 3 preguntas para cada gasto: el motivo, el lugar y la cantidad. Tras cada gasto introducido, el programa te preguntará si quieres introducir otro gasto más. Al finalizar, el programa debe imprimir todos los gastos en el mismo orden que los introdujiste y la cantidad total de dinero gastado. este es mi programa y el error;

```
  respuesta =input('¿Quieres introducir un gasto?:(si/no)')

  lista_gastos_totales=[]
  cantidad_total=0
  while respuesta == 'si':

     info_gasto = {}

     info_gasto['motivo']=input('Motivo del gasto:')

     info_gasto['lugar']=input('Lugar del gasto:')

     info_gasto['cantidad']=float(input('Cantidad del gasto:'))
     cantidad_total = cantidad_total + int(info_gasto['cantidad'])

     lista_gastos_totales.append(info_gasto)
     respuesta = input('¿Quieres introducir un gasto?:(si/no)')
  print('Gastos:')

  for values in  lista_gastos_totales:
     print(lista_gastos_totales['motivo'], 'en' , lista_gastos_totales['lugar'] , ':', 
     lista_gastos_totales['cantidad'], '$.')

  print('Cantidad total gastada:', cantidad_total, '$.')
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Greciano Tena\Desktop\ej3.py", line 26, in 
print(lista_gastos_totales['motivo'], 'en' , lista_gastos_totales['lugar'] , ':', lista_gastos_totales['cantidad'], '$.')
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

El error aparece porque en la siguiente línea pusiste un cambio de línea (Enter)

```
print(lista_gastos_totales['motivo'], 'en' , lista_gastos_totales['lugar'] , ':', 
lista_gastos_totales['cantidad'], '$.')
```

Si deseas separar una línea de código que tal vez es muy larga en 2 o más filas entonces debes utiliar `\` al final de cada línea que deseas "interrumpir"

```
print(values['motivo'], 'en' , values['lugar'] , ':', \ #<-- aquí 
    values['cantidad'], '$.')
```

Por cierto, tu código tiene un error, en el `for` deberías utilizar `values` y no `lista_gastos_totales` ya que `values` es la variable que itera tu lista

Otra cosa, tu código no evalúa si el usuario escribe "SI" (En mayúsculas), podrías agregar el método `lower()` al `input()`

```
respuesta =input('¿Quieres introducir un gasto?:(si/no)').lower()
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
respuesta =input('¿Quieres introducir un gasto?:(si/no)').lower()

lista_gastos_totales=[]
cantidad_total=0
while respuesta == 'si':

    info_gasto = {}

    info_gasto['motivo']=input('Motivo del gasto:')

    info_gasto['lugar']=input('Lugar del gasto:')

    info_gasto['cantidad']=float(input('Cantidad del gasto:'))
    cantidad_total = cantidad_total + int(info_gasto['cantidad'])

    lista_gastos_totales.append(info_gasto)
    respuesta = input('¿Quieres introducir un gasto?:(si/no)').lower()
print('Gastos:')

for values in  lista_gastos_totales:
    print(values['motivo'], 'en' , values['lugar'] , ':', values['cantidad'], '$.')

print('Cantidad total gastada:', cantidad_total, '$.')
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me fuiste de gran ayuda, un saludo